# How to get each customers entry and exit to the shop?

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table

I have a dataset of each customer being captured by the sensors at different times.So the customer will enter the shop and will be captured by sensor_id 1 and the customer also can enter through sensor_id 2. But the customer can only exit through sensor_id 3.The data set looks like below :

```
library(data.table)
library(lubridate)
DT1 <- data.table(
  customer_id=c(1,1,1,2,2,2,1,1),
  sensor_id=c(1,2,3,1,2,3,2,3),
  in_time=c("2017-01-01 00:00:05","2017-01-01 00:06:35","2017-01-01 00:23:44","2017-01-02 22:00:20","2017-01-02 22:01:09","2017-01-02 22:28:02","2017-01-03 22:23:01","2017-01-03 22:50:52")
  )

DT1[,in_time:=ymd_hms(in_time)]
```

So from this, I wanted to get the data frame

```
result <- data.table(
  customer_id=c(1,2,1),
  entry_sensor_id=c(1,1,2),
  entry_time=c("2017-01-01 00:00:05","2017-01-02 22:00:20","2017-01-03 22:23:01"),
  entry_sensor_id=c(3,3,3),
  exit_Time=c("2017-01-01 00:23:44","2017-01-02 22:28:02","2017-01-03 22:50:52")

)
```

So I tried the below :

```
DT1[, spotted_group := rleid( cumsum(difftime(in_time, 
                                                          shift(in_time, fill = first(in_time)), units = "mins") > 120)), customer_id]


DT1Stretch=DT1[ DT1[order(in_time), .I[c(1L,.N)], by=list(customer_id,spotted_group)]$V1 ]

DT1Stretch[,c(.SD[1,] , .SD[2,]),by=c("customer_id","spotted_group")]
```

But this approach does not work if the customer returns back to the shop within 2 hours since I label the spotted_group based on the 120 minutes difference which is not ideal.

Not sure which is the right way to deal with my problem. Any help is appreciated.

To label the groups of the customer staying in the shop and getting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this answer your question :

```
library(data.table)
library(lubridate)

DT <- data.table(
  customer_id=c(1,1,1,2,2,2,1,1),
  sensor_id=c(1,2,3,1,2,3,2,3),
  in_time=c("2017-01-01 00:00:05","2017-01-01 00:06:35","2017-01-01 00:23:44","2017-01-02 22:00:20","2017-01-02 22:01:09","2017-01-02 22:28:02","2017-01-03 22:23:01","2017-01-03 22:50:52")
)
DT[,in_time:=lubridate::ymd_hms(in_time)]

# For both sensors 1&2 customer is in
DT[, customer_in:= ifelse(sensor_id %in% c(1,2),T,F)]

# Aggregate sensors 1 & 2, find first entry time
inout <- DT[order(customer_id,in_time)][, .(in_time = min(in_time),customer_in) , by = .(customer_id,rleid(customer_in),customer_in)]

# Separate entry & exit
entry <- inout[customer_in == T]
exit <- inout[customer_in == F]

# Join results
entry[exit,.(customer_id,in_time=x.in_time,out_time=in_time),roll=Inf, on=.(customer_id,in_time)]
```

```
   customer_id             in_time            out_time
1:           1 2017-01-01 00:00:05 2017-01-01 00:23:44
2:           2 2017-01-02 22:00:20 2017-01-02 22:28:02
3:           1 2017-01-03 22:23:01 2017-01-03 22:50:52
```

Comment: This works for small datasets.But for larger datasets, I do not get sequential rleid in the data table inout for the customer and it is failing to select min(in_time) instead selects all entries (through  sensor_id 1,2 ) not only min (in_time).Any idea why ?

Comment: EDIT: When I order by the cutomer_id only I was able to but it is not ordered by customer_id but by in_time it fails though

Comment: The proposed logic assumed that in_time was ascending, customer ID shouldn't have an influence because it belongs to the by.

Comment: however, to be sure I updated the code with an order by customer_id,in_time. Let me know if everything is now ok on larger datasets.

Answer (score 2):

Here is another option using `unique` by exit sensor & time after a rolling join:

```
unique(
  DT1[sensor_id==3L][DT1[sensor_id!=3L], on=.(customer_id, in_time), roll=-Inf,
    .(customer_id, entry_sensor_id=i.sensor_id, entry_time=i.in_time,
      exit_sensor_id=3L, exit_time=x.in_time)],
  by=c("customer_id", "exit_sensor_id", "exit_time"))
```